Difficulty upgrading Ruby version via Homebrew
I am struggling to update my Ruby version via Homebrew. I don't quite understand what's going on. Below, you can see my terminal says Ruby 3.3.1 is 'arealdy installed' but then when I look at the version it says 2.6.10. How do I resolve this?
wesleypigg@192 ~ % rbenv install 3.3.1
rbenv: /Users/wesleypigg/.rbenv/versions/3.3.1 already exists
continue with installation? (y/N) n
wesleypigg@192 ~ % rbenv global 3.3.1
wesleypigg@192 ~ % ruby -v 
ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.arm64e- darwin23]

I'm ultimately trying to install cocoapods which requires a newer version of ruby.
I've just done the below but it still says it's the old version.
$ brew update
$ brew install ruby-build
$ brew install rbenv

$ rbenv install 3.3.1
$ rbenv global 3.3.1

Here's my PATH in case it's helpful for providing context. I don't quite know enough about PATH to know whether this is contributing. I've also pasted my zshrc. file in case useful.
 /opt/homebrew/bin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin
/usr/local/bin
/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin
/Users/wesleypigg/Library/Application

zshrc. file:
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Users/wesleypigg/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts

eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"

if [ -d "/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin" ]; then
  export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH
  export PATH=`gem environment gemdir`/bin:$PATH
fieval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

Thanks and apologies in advance, I'm a huge newbie. Go easy on me.

You have installed rbenv but apparently you are not using it. See https://www.biteinteractive.com/how-to-get-started-with-pods/

It is possible that for some reason the system ruby shows up in your PATH prior to rbenv. Maybe try running rbenv init? Docs

On MacOS, rbenv needs to be integrated into your ~/.zprofile as all terminal windows are login windows unless you do some manual things. It also looks for various Ruby things within your home directory, while installing it via Homebrew installs it somewhere under  brew --prefix). Don't do this with Homebrew; use rbenv and ruby-build, or chruby and ruby-install, or some other sensible combination.

@engineersmnky I have added photos of my PATH and zshrc file if that's helpful as I'm not sure how to check your comments

The screen shot tell that you have rvm and rbenv installed that the same time. You need to decide for one of them and fully deinstall the other Ruby version manager.

Also please do not post pictures of text. Text is text. Copy it, paste it into your question, and format it (as code, for example).

Thanks @spickermann that's helpful. I have removed rvm. Still seems to give me the same problem.

Thanks @matt. Again - newbie here so that is helpful to know. I will edit to remove the images and insert code instead.

@engineersmnky thank you. How would I know if system ruby shows up first? and how would I change this? I've tried rbev init and it doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

To know what Ruby you are using, say which Ruby.

From your description, it feels like you only did step 1 from "Installing – Using Package Managers", but not steps 2 and 3 like described in their README.


Set up your shell to load rbenv.
rbenv init


Close your Terminal window and open a new one so your changes take effect.




I have followed each step in the link you provided and it still provides me with v2.6, unfortunately
